# PHP DI Annotations don't work

Tags: php, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm, inject, php-di

I have just started using `PHP-DI` and it is awesome, however I cannot manage to solve one issue.

Here is my services definitions

```
<?php

return [
    'services.report'=> DI\autowire( '\CRM\Report\Service\ReportService' ),
    '\CRM\Report\Service\ReportServiceContract' => DI\get ( 'services.report' )
];
```

And my class defined as follows

```
class ReportService implements ReportServiceContract {
    private $repository;

    /**
     * ReportService constructor.
     * @Inject("repositories.report_tasks")
     *
     * @param $repository
     */
    public function __construct( $repository ) {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        var_dump( $this->repository->getReportTaskById( 1 )->getDateSubmitted() );
    }

}
```

Having that configuration I am getting the following error

> Entry "services.report" cannot be resolved: Parameter $repository of
>   __construct() has no value defined or guessable
>       Full definition:
>       Object (
>           class = \CRM\Report\Service\ReportService
>           lazy = false
>           __construct(
>               $repository = #UNDEFINED#
>           )
>       )

I have tried to debug sources, and noticed that even an `AnnotationReader` instance is not created.

But when using the following definition

```
 <?php

    return [
'services.report' => DI\autowire( '\CRM\Report\Service\ReportService' )->constructorParameter('repository',DI\get('repositories.report_tasks')),
        '\CRM\Report\Service\ReportServiceContract' => DI\get ( 'services.report' )
    ];
```

Everything works fine.

What is wrong with my configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

To use annotations they need to be enabled (they are disabled by default): http://php-di.org/doc/annotations.html#installation

> Annotations **are disabled by default**. To be able to use them, you first need to install the [Doctrine Annotations](http://doctrine-common.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations.html) library using Composer:
>
> ```
> composer require doctrine/annotations
> ```
>
> Then you need to configure the `ContainerBuilder` to use them:
>
> ```
> $containerBuilder->useAnnotations(true);
> ```